# How to : Single Connection for Single Page in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlconnection

I have a page where I am using 8-10 Usercontrols for displaying dynamic data. All usercontrols are using repeaters on them for databinding, so from this single page I have 8-10 connections in a single request for a single user. I am using conventional way of fetching data from Sql Server database that is SqlHelperClass (closing and disposing each connection when done. I am taking care of that.) `->` DataLayer `->` BusinessLayer and then UI.

So I just want to know :

1. Is there any settings in IIS
2. Any settings in web.config
3. Settings in Sql Server

So that I can avoid multiple connections in a single request. Or any other approach for similar situation.

Comment: What you really need to avoid is multiple requests to SQL Server

Comment: yes , if we see here on page load we have 10 connections for a single user , so for simultaneous 100 users it will be 1000 hits to Sql Server and so on... But If i anyhow pull all data in single hit then i have 100 connections only..900 less hits to my sql database. So based on my scenario , i need some example or references. Thanks

Comment: What problem you got to let 8-10 connection in single requests?

Comment: I am worried about the delay in request processing if the number of simultaneous users increases. Since its going to be a public website and number of user hits at once will be around 200-500. This is targeted, 10-20% tolerance is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily [ADO.NET already uses connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) to automatically take care of this for you.

It is not advisable to handle many open/close connects by yourself. Just use the using statement to properly dispose of managed resources.

Comment: I am taking proper care of SqlConnection close and dispose. Each connection is disposed after the proper execution of the query and result set returns.

Comment: using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
  connectionString))
  {
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }

Answer (score 0):

have one data source for the page instead of one for each control. Usercontrols shouldn't worry about have they get their data they should worry about how it's rendered on screen

Comment: sorry, i did'nt get you- "Usercontrols should worry about have they get their data they should worry about how it's rendered on screen"

Comment: @AmitRanjan it's a typo the word I wanted to write was **shouldn't** sorry for the confusion